# Link shared on Facebook shows preview as just domain name until new scrape initiated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am testing an app update with a test user which shares a link to a newly created page. What I'm seeing is that the shared link preview just has the domain of the url. When I view the url in the debug tool it shows the same but if I force a scrape of the content it then appears correctly.

Here can see the debug content initially and after forcing scrape
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLN2l.jpg

I have tried variations on meta data and that has no effect. The link "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" presents the same content before or after new scrape.

Any suggestions of what might be going on or how to resolve?

Comment: Facebook needs to read your meta data at least once, before it can render a full preview. You can [trigger a scrape via API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update) – so if your CMS allows for that, I recommend implementing a step that triggers a re-scrape whenever an article is published or updated.

Comment: @CBroe that did the trick... add as answer and you get the points :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook needs to read your meta data at least once, before it can render a full preview.

You can [trigger a scrape via API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update) – so if your CMS allows for that, I recommend implementing a step that triggers a (re-)scrape whenever an article is published or updated.